# Find global variables without nm or other external tools

Tags: c++, c

Is there any way to find all global variables, WITHOUT using nm or other tools, which requires an installation in Windows?

My idea was to find all global variables manually with a perl script by looking into the linker *.map file. Is this a way to do it?

Comment: Is perl not an external tool?

Comment: of course, but: on every company-pc is perl installed, but nm not:(

Comment: I'd use nm and make a installer package that can run in silent mode, or an SFX (self extract), or a simple ZIP, if that makes things simpler for you. Then you can include the nm binary and its dependencies, if any.

Comment: Why not get perl to install nm for you and use that

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to extract that information from a linker map file. Cf. https://balau82.wordpress.com/2013/11/24/analyzing-c-source-files-dependencies-in-a-program/ for an example about a similar albeit more complicated project with Python.

I see two possible things which could go wrong:

1. The map file format apparently is not (designed to be) stable; iiuc you are basically relying on an undocumented feature when you parse it for information.
2. The map file produced by the linker conceivably changes with the locale. That can possibly bite your script whenever somebody has fancy locales on. (Setting LC_LANG or LC_ALL locally to e.g. "C" in the script should fix that though.)